# React Native UnableToResolveError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, import, create-react-native-app

I've been doing React for ~2 years, I've started learning React Native a few days ago and immediately ran into a wall.

I'm trying to import a simple .jsx file into my App.js:

```
import PostsPage from './pages/PostsPage/PostsPageContainer.jsx';
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

Unable to resolve ./pages/PostsPage/PostsPageContainer.jsx" from ".//App.js`: could not resolve`/Users/MyUser/Documents/app-name/pages/PostsPage/PostsPageContainer.jsx' as a file nor as a folder","name":"UnableToResolveError","type":"UnableToResolveError","errors":[{}]},"type":"bundling_error"}"

There's a [huge thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14209) on this error but it's all people trying to import outside modules. I'm trying to import a regular .jsx file which I'd created myself. I've double and triple-checked that the file does exist and it's spelled right. I've also tried restarting the packager and clearing cache.

I've used `‎create-react-native-app` to create this app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your file extensions in react-native, use **.js** instead of **.jsx**. The default extension is **.js** unless you want to disable that rule.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an issue I had and solved by removing the hyphen from the folder name: https://github.com/bnovf/react-native-github-graphql-app/issues/15

I can see your file path has a `.../app-name/..`, change it to `appname` or appName and dont use underscore i.e `app_name`

I dont know the reason but that helped me.